# Type safe TypeScript method wrapper helper by function name

Tags: typescript

There are lots of Q&As about making a function wrapper in typescript and that works. My question is how to do I do the same with named methods? What I want to write is something like this JavaScript

```js
  function wrap(API, fnName, fn) {
     const origFn = API.prototype[fnName];
     API.prototype[fnName] = function(...args) {
        fn(...args);
        return origFn.call(this, ...args);
     };
   }

   wrap(CanvasRenderingContext2D, 'fillRect', function(x, y, w, h) {
      console.log(x, y, w, h);
   });
   
   // --- check it worked ---
   const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
   ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 100, 40);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Further, ideally I'd like to use lists of functions or functions on objects like this

```js
function wrap(API, fnName, fn) {
     const origFn = API.prototype[fnName];
     API.prototype[fnName] = function(...args) {
        fn(...args);
        return origFn.call(this, ...args);
     };
   }

   const wrappers = {
     fillRect(x, y, w, h) {
       console.log('fill:', x, y, w, h);
     },
     strokeRect(x, y, w, h) {
       console.log('stroke:', x, y, w, h);
     },
   };

   for (const [name, fn] of Object.entries(wrappers)) {
     wrap(CanvasRenderingContext2D, name, fn);
   }
   
   // --- check it worked ---
   const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
   ctx.fillRect(10, 20, 100, 40);
   ctx.strokeRect(40, 70, 20, 40);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Is it possible to write either of these forms in a typesafe way in TypeScript? Where, based on names of the functions it check if the function being associated with the method matches types?

Note: For my actual use case, the functions will be doing more work than just `console.log` and will need to know they are using the types correctly.

Comment: So, uh, I'm wondering what your typing use cases are here; I'd think you'd care more about callers of `wrap()` seeing good typings than the implementation... so maybe something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOXyRN) would meet your needs?  Note that some of your other code is going to be tough since you're running into issues of inference (how do you want TS to know the method param types of `wrappers `?) and other things like `Object.entries()` not giving strong enough types... so I think you might want to constrain yourself to just the top case if possible. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks. That works. I can see why the loop thing with `Object.entries()` doesn't work but I think you can extract the keys with something like `function keysOf<T extends string>(obj: { [k in T]: unknown }): readonly T[] {
  return Object.keys(obj) as unknown[] as T[];
}` and they'll be only keys that map to something in the object. Not a ts guru enough to know if that's a step to the second style.

Comment: You can do all kinds of things to try to get that to work, but it seems out of scope for this question, which is primarily about the call signature for `wrap()` and less about how the language in general deals with iterating over object types and known/unknown keys.  Yes, your approach is one way to proceed.  So, is it okay if I write up my version of `wrap()` as an answer and explain how it works?  Or am I missing something you need for a complete answer?

Comment: Sure, your answer is fine. I can ask another about iterating over methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we care mostly about the experience for *callers* of `wrap()` and are not really worried about having the compiler type check its *implementation*, then I would make it look like this:

```
function wrap<
  K extends PropertyKey,
  T extends Record<K, (...args: any) => any>
>(
  API: { prototype: T },
  fnName: K, 
  fn: T[K]
) {
  const origFn = API.prototype[fnName];
  API.prototype[fnName] = function (this: T, ...args: any) {
    fn(...args);
    return origFn.call(this, ...args);
  } as any;
}
```

Here `wrap()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) both in the type `K` of `fnName`, which we expect to be a [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like `"fillRect"`, and the type `T` of the instance type of `API`, which we [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be a type with a function property at key `K`.

Since `fnName` is of type `K`, then when you call `wrap()`, the compiler should infer `K` from the corresponding argument. And since `API` is of type `{prototype: T}`, then the compiler should infer `T` from the `prototype` property of that argument, and check it against the constraint that `API.prototype` has a function-valued property at the `fnName` key.

And finally, `fn` is of type `T[K]`, the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) corresponding to the type of `API.prototype[fnName]`.  So `fn` is expected to be the same function type, and even better, if you pass in `fn` as a function expression, the compiler will be able to infer the types of its parameters [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).

---

Let's test it out:

```
wrap(CanvasRenderingContext2D, 'fillRect',
  function (x, y, w, h) {
    // TS knows that x, y, w, and h are numbers
    console.log(x.toFixed(), y.toFixed(), w.toFixed(), h.toFixed());
  });
```

Looks good. The compiler infers `"fillRect"` for `K` and `CanvasRenderingContext2D` (the type, not the constructor value) for `T`.  And thus it sees the call signature as:

```
/* function wrap<"fillRect", CanvasRenderingContext2D>(
     API: { prototype: CanvasRenderingContext2D; }, 
     fnName: "fillRect", 
     fn: (x: number, y: number, w: number, h: number) => void
   ): void */
```

So `fn()`'s four parameters are all expected to be `number`s.  And indeed, as seen above, the compiler infers this from context. So in `function (x, y, w, h) {⋯}` above, you didn't have to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) the parameters yourself for this to work.

---

So there you go, that should work, at least to a first approximation.  It can be a bit more involved getting things that will work as you want with loops, or with `fn` arguments declared ahead of time, but these concerns are mostly about how to use TypeScript in the face of various restrictions/limitations/assumptions of the language, and little to do with `wrap()` itself.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAeAUIxAaUQFMAPKEsAEwGdEAFVOTE1KAT0JI4Bp9EAFVIUqdRACUSEOKmrZCvRAAoAdOvSoA5rQBcidGA4BKRAF4AfAaMXcF5QICCDAJL6A3okzMocTq31hAF9+AmAwADl0AFsSfUVEcMCAbUIAXVxTdwEZMFooRFkYLQAxJDNEZxdVbz8-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)